# How to mount NFS share to spawned containers in JupyterHub?

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-swarm, jupyterhub

I'm trying to configure JupyterHub server on the DockerSwarm. I can not mount NFS folder straight to the container spawned by JupyterHub service.

I tried to mount it using docker-compose to JupyterHub service and then mount it at locally mounted folder to spawned containers and it works, but now we have a bottle neck at this service because everytime containers need to work with files it go first to JupyterHub service and then to NFS share. I want to make it go right to NFS share from spawned container, but it doesn't seem like an easy job to do.

To mount nfs right to the container I used the next code in jupyterhub_config.py

```
mounts = [
    {
        'type': 'volume',
        'target': USER_WORKDIR,
        'source': 'jhub-user-{username}',
        'driver_config': {
            'name': 'local',
            'options': {
                'type': 'nfs',
                'o': NFS_IP + ',rw',
                'device': ':/opt/nfs/share'
            }
        }
    }
]

c.SwarmSpawner.extra_container_spec = {'mounts': mounts}
```

In that case I can login to the container but the volume for user doesn't creating.

Another way I tried is to put this code to `pre_spawn_hook` so it looks like this

```
def pre_spawn_hook(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name

    mounts = [
        {
            'type': 'volume',
            'target': USER_WORKDIR,
            'source': 'jhub-user-{username}',
            'driver_config': {
                'name': 'local',
                'options': {
                    'type': 'nfs',
                    'o': NFS_IP + ',rw',
                    'device': ':/opt/nfs/share'
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    spawner.extra_container_spec = {'mounts': mounts}

c.SwarmSpawner.pre_spawn_hook = pre_spawn_hook
```

In that case it creates for each user on login its own volume but those volumes don't have access to NFS folder for some reason.

Also, just `exec` to a spawned container and run `mount` command doesn't work.

Thanks.